# How do you say 'more egalitarian' in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

And please help me to translate the example sentence:

> The lack of gender in English is not due to the English having a more egalitarian culture.

I want to use this sentence when I am arguing with someone ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[John Well’s dictionary](https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/508176) has the following:

> **egalitarian** egalrajt-iga, -isma

So maybe you could translate the phrase with:

> La manko de genro en la angla ne estas pro tio ke angloj havos pli **egalrajtisman** kulturon.

Answer (score 1):

La manko de genro en la angla ne estas pro (tio ke/la fakto ke) la angloj havas **pli egalecan** kulturon.